# ming extensions before_insert not creating new objects

Tags: python, mongodb, ming

I am trying to insert a new Role or Roles that are required for a new User that is being created. But for some reason the roles are not created. Any idea why the role is not created but the User is? The session shows the Role in

```
class UserExtension(MapperExtension):

  def before_insert(self, obj, status, session):
    role_user_id = Role(context='user', context_id=obj._id)
    obj.role_ids.append(role_user_id._id)

class User(BaseMappedClass):

  class __mongometa__:
    session = DBSession
    name = 'users'
    unique_indexes = [('email',)]
    extensions = [UserExtension, ModifiedExtension]
```

I tried using session.save(role_user_id) but still no new document.

Comment: I actually ended up using session.flush(role_user_id), and this worked!

Answer (score 0):

```
session.flush(role_user_id)
```

works.